# Request for member, non class-type

Tags: c++

i'm getting huge amount of errors in my code, and it all boils down to the following:

Library.cpp:89: error: request for member ‘getLocation’ in ‘((Library*)this)->Library::holdings.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = Book*, _Alloc = std::allocator](((long unsigned int)bookOnFile))’, which is of non-class type ‘Book*’

i'm just so confused as to how I should write the following:

```
        Patron* matchPatron = &members[patronOnFile];
    if (PatronIDMatch == true && bookIDMatch == true) {
        if (holdings[bookOnFile].getLocation() == ON_SHELF) {
            holdings[bookOnFile].setCheckedOutBy(matchPatron);
            holdings[bookOnFile].setLocation(CHECKED_OUT);
            holdings[bookOnFile].setDateCheckedOut(currentDate);
            members[patronOnFile].setCheckedOutBooks(&holdings[bookOnFile]);
            cout << members[patronOnFile].getName() << " check out successful"
                << holdings[bookOnFile].getTitle() << ".";
```

(i have the error code for so many lines, this one is just for the getLocation line.)

and my header is the following:

```
    //Library.hpp
#ifndef LIBRARY_HPP
#define LIBRARY_HPP
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Patron.hpp"

class Library {

private:
    std::vector<Book*> holdings;
    std::vector<Patron*> members;
    int currentDate;

public:
    Library();
    void addBook(Book*);
    void addPatron(Patron*);
    std::string checkOutBook(std::string pID, std::string bID);
    std::string returnBook(std::string bID);
    std::string requestBook(std::string pID, std::string bID);
    std::string payFine(std::string pID, double payment);
    void incrementCurrentDate();
    Patron* getPatron(std::string pID);
    Book* getBook(std::string bID);
};
#endif
```

am i just writing my code wrong here? how should I be writing it? i can provide my entire program if needed.

EDIT:

```
Patron* matchPatron = &members[patronOnFile];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector of `Book*`, which are pointers, but you are using dot notation when you call `holdings[bookOnFile].getLocation()`. Same goes for the other method calls. Try replacing with `holdings[bookOnFile]->getLocation()`, etc.

Comment: ah christ, thanks a ton. also i got an error "cannot convert 'Patron**' to 'Patron*' in intialization. Any idea what that means? I included that line in the post as well.

Comment: Similar concept, you're storing Patron pointers inside of your `members` vector. The statement `&members[patronOnFile];` indexes the vector, gets a `Patron*`, then takes the _address_ of that pointer. Now you have a pointer to a pointer to a Patron (a `Patron**`). My guess is you meant to write that statement without the ampersand.